# Postgresql rule on insert to do nothing and return the given instence

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-data-r2dbc

I am trying to write a rule that on insert if there is conflict to do nothing. The hard part is that I am using java code for interacting with the db and the save method expects an instance to be returned. So the goal I am trying to achieve is, a rule that triggers on conflict when inserting, does nothing and returns the given instance.
I have tried to do something like that :

```
CREATE RULE "my_rule" AS ON INSERT TO "table_x"
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_x WHERE id = NEW.id)
DO INSTEAD
Select * from table_x WHERE(id=NEW.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a rule for that, use instead :

```
INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

Comment: Not using sql directly, the db interactions go through ReactiveCrudRepository.

Answer (score 0):

I never use Postgresqls rules, but I'd expect that you could combine it with the idea of [Edouards answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70938804/66686).

```sql
CREATE RULE "my_rule" AS ON INSERT TO "table_x"
DO INSTEAD
INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```